# Hi may I ask help for visual studio for not showing the result

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner of python and CS, just find this confusing me so I find fib on here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html and try to get familiar with it and everything is alright for fib() but for the fib2() and the (fib.**name** )it doesn't show up when I run it in visual studio code, but when I run it in PowerShell it both work fine, can someone please explain how could I do this right.

Comment: Is you code the same as in the tutorial?

Comment: You might have not installed python in vs code or just try to restart vs code again

Comment: Yes, I do install python since the beginning, is version 3.9.6, and yes is totally the same i copy and paste work fine for fib, but not fib2

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `fib2` does not print the result. But in the PowerShell, it will print the result in default.

You need to print it by yourself in the VSCode:

```
fib(2)
print(fib2(2))
```

Comment: Ahh ok I got it that is what I thought as well thanks for you help buddy